# How to create Oauth2.0 in order to call FCM v1 API ? Swift

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am running a Vapor server and I want to call FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) API in order to send notifications to my IOS app. 
 In Firebase console we are presented with two keys *Server key* and *Legacy key*.
Reading  [firebase cloud-messaging/send-message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) docs I have learnt that I have to send a HTTP POST request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1 with an **access token** .

Reading further under [Authorize Send Requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server) I see there are different libraries (node.js, python) that enable one to generate an access token, but I think I will need to do that using REST since there is no library for SWIFT on server.

I can't find any library for swift to mint an OAUTH2.0 token using a service account and I was wondering if there is anyone who could show me how to mint the token using REST in Swift.

Comment: I answered the question about the use of server keys in your prior question.  Server keys aren't used in the v1 API, only the legacy API.  You need an Oauth token to use the v1 API.

Comment: Bear in mind that your request for a code example may cause people to vote to close this issue on the grounds of seeking external resources.  If I were you, I'd edit that question out and stick to your question about how to get an Oauth token in order to call the v1 API, given the absence of a Google-provided library in swift.

Comment: Hi @bibscy, were you able to figure this out eventually?